# Implementation of rectangle constructor in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm watching the lecture of [sicp 3a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QgZVYI3tDs&list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46&index=5) and he specifies a constructor and selector for `make-rect` but doesn't provide the implementation.

```
(define make-rect list)
(define make-vect cons) 
(define origin car) 
(define horiz cadr) 
(define vert caddr)

(define t (make-rect (make-vect 0 0) (make-vect 2 3) (make-vect 9 9)))


(origin t)
(horiz t)
(vert t)
```

I am unsure if this meets all the requirements for a rectangle constructor.

Comment: An implementation is as good as any other, as long as the required operations are supported. That's the whole idea of the data abstraction discipline: it doesn't matter how you do things under the hood.

Comment: If this code already works, then it's a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  Some points, though:You can call make-rect with any number of arguments. You can call make-vect with any *type* of arguments.  You can call origin, horiz, and vert, with things that weren't produced by make-rect/make-vect.  You might not want all these to be the case.

Comment: @benrudgers You're right, I didn't remember that part. I'm deleting my comment, as it no longer applies. Good catch!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I had to open my Wizard book (only then could I use the web).

Answer (score 0):

Three vectors are required to describe a rectangle that can be rotated. However, your code describes parallelograms rather than rectangles. There's no guarantee that

```
(= (+ (square (distance origin horizontal))
      (square (distance origin vertical)))
   (square (distance horizontal vertical)))
```

The analogous code (for parallelograms) in *SICP* is written in terms of `frames` in [Section 2.2.4](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.4) of the book.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not, because you can abuse it with something like

```
 (define t 
   (make-rect 
    (make-vect 'bacon '(and eggs)) 
    (make-vect 'coffee 'tea) 
    (make-vect '(I am not a point) '(and neither am I))))
```

for which

```
 (origin t)
 (horiz t)
 (vert t)
```

returns

```
 '(bacon and eggs)
 '(coffee . tea)
 '((I am not a point) and neither am I)
```

Comment: By that criterion, nearly all scheme code posted to StackOverflow would be bad, not to mention unvalidated code wired to databases or reading streams without exception handling in other languages.  And C code with pointers...well I don't want to think about it.

Comment: Scheme supports making the procedure check its arguments and it should do that sometimes. It's also ok to leave validation to the user. Scheme tradition is to have thin spec and one result is that what happens when you write `(car 5)` is implementation dependent. If Scheme segfaults it's a completely acceptable behaviour since the report addresses Scheme programs and not invalid Scheme programs. Valid Scheme programs never call `car` with any other value than pairs. Error situations got exceptions from R6RS but SICP-videos are old and use R3RS.